# Create sequence from multidimensional array in F#

Tags: f#

I'm new to F# and I've been struggling with this for a while. I have a two-dimensional array (`[,]`) and I want to get a sequence of all the elements in this array. While there seem to be options to iterate such an array (e.g. `Array2D.iter`), I want to pass the sequence to some other functions, not just iterate the elements.

In the end, I've worked around this with the following function:

```
let getAllElements (a: MyDiscriminatedUnionType[,]) : (seq<MyDiscriminatedUnionType>) =
    seq { for x in a do yield (x :?> MyDiscriminatedUnionType) }
```

this seems to work but looks very excessive to me. Since the `for .. in` expression works on an `enumerable-expression` there already seems to be a way to enumerate a multidimensional array more easily?

Also I can't really figure out how to make this function more generic, so that this isn't tied to `MyDiscriminatedUnionType` but works with all multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the second part of your question, you can make the function generic by replacing `MyDiscriminatedUnionType` type with a generic type parameter such as `'a`:

```
let getAllElements (a:'a[,]) : seq<'a> =
    seq { for x in a do yield x :?> 'a }
```

I think the code is quite clean - it would be nice if there was a built-in function for this (say, `Array2D.toSeq`) and I think it would be reasonable to suggest this as an addition to the standard F# library, but I don't think there is a function like this - and then the sequence expression is a nice way of writing this.

The only annoying thing is that you have to cast `x` using `x :?> 'a`. This is because the 2D array type does not implement a generic `IEnumerable<'a>` interface, but only the (old style) non-generic version.

You could avoid that by iterating over the indices and indexing into the array, which is a bit longer, but avoids the ugly casting:

```
let getAllElements (a:'a[,]) : seq<'a> =
    seq { for i in 0 .. a.GetLength(0)-1 do
          for j in 0 .. a.GetLength(1)-1 do yield a.[i,j] }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with the generic parameter, I somehow failed to figure out the correct syntax for that. Glad to see I didn't miss something major here and this just seems to be a limitation of multidimensional arrays.